# How elasticsearch statistics IP pair data

Tags: elasticsearch

How to get total IP pair count by Elasticsearch 7?

**mapping defined:**

```
...
"srcIp": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
"destIp": {
    "type": "keyword"
}
...
```

**And definition of ip pair:**

```
A.srcIp == B.destIp && A.destIp == B.srcIp
```

**Desired result: **total pair count.

Comment: By `A` and `B` you mean different documents?

Comment: @Val yes A and B means different Docs